# How to append a string in front of string in C

Tags: c, string, printf, c-strings

I have a string in C : "Phone/mis. ie Credit Card pmnt". Its length is 30 chars. I want to append a string in front of this "R*". So that my final output stands as "R* Phone/mis. ie Credit Card p".
String truncates over here at the end as its max length is 30 chars.
I have tried below code where iov_pPymArr->pymInfoArray[i].type_desc variable contains string "Phone/mis. ie Credit Card pmnt":

```
sprintf (iov_pPymArr->pymInfoArray[i].type_desc,"R*%s",iov_pPymArr->pymInfoArray[i].type_desc);

But it gives me output as : "R*R*e/mis. ie Credit Card pmnt".
```

R* is getting appended twice and string is getting truncated from beginning instead of end. Please advice the possible Solution.

Comment: `char new_str [LARGE_ENOUGH] = "some new string";
    strcat(new_str, old_str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `sprintf` in-place. The solution to your problem is to use a temporary buffer.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to write a buffer to itself is *undefined behavior*.

Use `sprintf` (or even better, `snprintf`) to write to another temporary buffer, and copy that to the actual buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to absolutely minimize your memory usage and your string buffer is large enough, you can use `memmove` to make space at the front of it (from the space past the null terminator which needs to be there unless you want a segfault) and then memcpy the prefix to the front, without the terminating zero.

```
#define STR " Phone/mis. ie Credit Card p"
#define PREFIX "R*"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  char buff[sizeof(STR) + 2] = STR;
  memmove(buff + 2, buff, sizeof(buff) - 2);
  memcpy(buff, PREFIX, 2);
  puts(buff);
}
```

**Output:**

```
R* Phone/mis. ie Credit Card p
```

Note: `Appending in the front` is called `prepending`.

Answer (score 0):

Writting a Buffer into itself using sprintf is undefined and not legal means of coding. Use strcat or a temporary buffer instead.